# Multiple lines automatically-resizeable UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I want to insert a couple of strings to my `UITextView` so they are displayed vertically

Tried this code:

```
NSMutableString* examinationsString = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSString * examination in examinationsArray)
{
    [examinationsString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %s ",examination, "\n"]];
}

return examinationsString;
```

I had changed `UITextView` Lines property to 5 but still getting all in one line, separated with "/"

What am I doing wrong?

I'd also want the `UITextView` to stretch if there are more than 1 line, if it's not achieved automatically of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following code:

```
NSMutableString* examinationsString = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSString * examination in examinationsArray)
{
    [examinationsString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,\n",examination]];
}
return examinationsString;
```

Now to resize the `UITextView` as per the view's `contentSize`:

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[examinationsString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,\n",examination]];
```

Comment: that's correct. now what would be the best approach to resize the UITextView if there are more than 1 element? Can't I set its height dynamic soehow?