# How to resize the UITextField in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

**-** How to increase the height of the text field in order **to accommodate multiple lines, as the text field grows accordingly.**

**-** I want something like `multiple line attribute` in **android**.

Comment: You can use textview for multiple line.

Comment: You need to use a `UITextView` if you want to use multiple lines as `UITextField` doesn't support multiple lines. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681050/multiple-lines-automatically-resizeable-uitextview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HPGrowingTextView for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hpgrowingtextview) for multiple lines textview

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` not supporting multiple lines text place `UITextView` in the place of `UITextField`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at UITextView and not a UITextField.